# not able to retrieve the last inserted id from sql in html

Tags: php, html, sql

i am trying to display some values from database to my html calling the last inserted id

```html
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * from registers where id= LAST_INSERT_ID()";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (!empty($result) && $result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo " $row[firstname] ";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

But when I am using this, the result is not being displayed, is there any problem with my code, how do I retrieve the last inserted id from sql?

Comment: i didnt see any INSERT query in your script

Comment: @devpro i didnt insert anything, values are already there in database

Comment: then what are expecting with this `LAST_INSERT_ID()` ? `LAST_INSERT_ID()` for what?

Comment: according to PHP manual `Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query (usually INSERT).`

Comment: @devpro i am new to sql, i just want to know how to retrieve the last id in the table

Comment: all the values are inserted from user submitted form. id is auto genretaed... is there any way

Comment: @Kaddath yes its is

Comment: Note that this will not necessarily retreive the last id in your table, in case of multiple insert, it will return the **first** generated id of that insert. Also, what you get if you run `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`?

Comment: share the code where you are inserting data from form

Comment: @Kaddath i am not getting anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query

```
$sql = "SELECT * from registers ORDER BY ID DESC limit 1 ";
```

it will give you only one result and this result will be the last inserted ID.
But ID needs to be auto increment.

Comment: First, it will retreive the complete row, not only the id, and second, `id` doesn't need to be set to `AUTO_INCREMENT` for this to work

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the last id in the table you need:

```
SELECT id FROM registers ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```